# What is the role of cakey.pem and cacert.pem in addition to .key and .crt based encryption

Tags: encryption, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption

I have `.key` file which holds the private key data, `.crt` file which would be certificate with public key and, to my knowledge, that's it for public key encryption, right?

Not exactly. In order to achieve my goal I must also generate cakey.pem and cacert.pem, which I do not know what they are for.

I have example with setting up TLS with Postfix MTA.

I do:

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > smtpd.key
openssl req -new -key smtpd.key -x509 -days 3650 -out smtpd.crt
```

these two - smtpd.key and smtpd.crt - are key (private key) and certificate (with public key incorporated).

what is the

```
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 3650
```

cakey.pem and cacert.pem files for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need a [Certificate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). A self-signed certificate is perfectly valid by itself. Indeed, it is its own CA.

If you want to use a dedicated CA, you need to sign `smtpd.crt` with the CA instead. CAs are used to establish a chain of trust. If a client trusts a CA, it automatically trusts all certificates signed by it.

Here’s a guide to create a self-signed CA and sign a certificate with it, taken from [Parallels](http://kb.parallels.com/en/118354):

- `openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048`
- `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -days 3650 -out rootCA.pem`
- `openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048`
- `openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr`
- `openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 730`

Comment: I think I do need CA. If I, for example, omit to specify smtpd_tls_CAfile, it wont work. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) is reference

Comment: Well, the guide is broken. The way the certificates are generated, they have no relation whatsoever. I’ll edit the post to include a guide from Parallels.

Comment: true for broken guide and also for generating CA. Thank you!